# Programmatically added controls not showing when added to a tab page

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, controls

Up till now I have been just displaying my programmatically created controls to this.controls but now I want to add in tabbing functionality for large sets of data. I added in a tab control and in the code I have the programmatic controls added to the tabpage but I cannot get the controls to display... help what do I need to do get the controls to display

right now what i have is

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel = new Panel();
    panel.Location = position;
    panel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    panel.Width = 240;
    panel.Height = 210;

    company = new Label();
    company.Location = new Point(panel.Location.X + 10, panel.Location.Y + 10);
    company.Text = tempServer.Value.companyName;
    company.Font = new Font(company.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Bold);

    tabs.TabPages["1"].Controls.Add(company);
    this.Controls.Add(tabs);
    this.Controls.SetChildIndex(tabs, this.Controls.Count);
}
```

Edit(to help clarify)
I have an application which reads from a database for each tuple in the data base my WinForm application creates a new panel which is then populated with various information with dynamically created labels. the position is then offset and the next panel is created. I was informed that i need to now have my application support tabs. each tab will only show so many panels. my problem accured when i tried to add these dynamically created panels to the tab control instead of this.control. when i did so the panels and their information was no longer being drawn and I cant figure out how to make the panels display

Comment: Well what you tried and which part didn't work? Post some code..

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set `Text` for your label so you didn't see any thing, try this:

```
company = new Label(){Text = "some text here"};
```

The whole code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  company = new Label{Text = "some text here"};
  tabs.TabPages["1"].Controls.Add(company);
  this.Controls.Add(tabs);    
}
```

Comment: i apalogize i do have the text set i missed putting the code above but i have edited it to show that i have

Comment: @user2952817 do you have any other control on your form (before adding your tabconrol)? Also please be sure that your `Load` event handler is subscribed correctly for your `Form.Load`, a quick check is simply by setting some break point in the `Form1_Load` handler and see if the code execution jumps in there.

Comment: several other labels and texboxs but they are set up the same and it is hitting the code

Comment: @user2952817 do you see your tab on your form? What's the `panel`? it should have the `Location` small enough so that the label does not go off the tabPage (because you set the Location of label according to the Location of `panel` with some offset)